# Prove that $|N_G(v)\cap Y|=d_B(v)$

Tags: graph-theory

G is a graph and B is a spanning bipartite subgraph of G such that B=B(X,Y) and v is any vertex in G
My work:
I know that $d_B(v)=|N_B(v)|$
So we have to prove that 
$N_B(v)=N_G(v)\cap Y$
It's clear that $N_B(v)\supseteq N_G(v)\cap Y$
is always true
I tried to prove the second direction by contradiction and I got $\exists vy\in E(G),y\in Y/vy\notin E(B)$

What should I do next ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understood the problem and your notations right, $v$ should be in $X$ (instead of $V(G)$) and the equality holds because $d_B(v)=|N_B(v)|$ and 
$$N_B(v)=\{u\in V(B): (v,u)\in E(G)\}= $$ $$\{u\in Y: (v,u)\in E(G)\}=N_G(v)\cap Y.$$

Comment: I understand why equality holds, but I wanted to give a proof by contradiction. BTW v is in X (sorry)

Comment: Oh. I think in order to have the equality, $B$ should be an *induced* subgraph of $G$, that is $E(B)=\{v’v’’\in E(G): v’,v’’\in B\}$. Then we got a contradiction, because if $y\in Y$ then $vy\in E(B)$, right?

Comment: Okay I understand your point but what if B was spanning subgraph.

Comment: If $B$ is not induced then the equality may fail. For instance, let $G$ be a complete graph with $|V(G)|=2n$ and let $V(G)=X\cup Y$ is a partition of $V(G)$ into two equal parts. Let $f:X\to Y$ be any bijection and $E(B)=\{xf(x):x\in X\}$. Then for each $v\in X$, $d_B(v)=1$, but $|N_G(v)\cap Y|=|Y|=n$.

Comment: How is this true $N_G(v)\cap Y=Y$ ? The intersection should be some unique element in Y

Comment: I understood that $N_G(v)$ is a neighborhood of $v$ in $G$. Since $G$ is a complete graph, $N_G(v)=V(G)\setminus\{v\}$. Since $v\not\in Y$, we have $N_G(v)\cap Y=Y$.

Comment: This makes sense,but if G is complete, is it possible to find a bipartite graph in it

Comment: Since $G$ is complete, any graph on the same set of vertices is its subgraph.

Comment:  thank you. And sorry for my silly questions :p